# Replace tags surrounding string only if string contains match

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I have a file with many lines containing strings surrounded by tags.

```
  <tag:identifier>99454</tag:identifier>
  <tag:identifier>97817(web)</tag:identifier>
  <tag:identifier>http://www.google.com</tag:identifier>
  <tag:title>Title String/</tag:title>
  <tag:creator>Example</tag:creator>
  <tag:creator>Field</tag:creator>
  <tag:creator>Country</tag:creator>
```

I am trying to find a way to change the tags around each URL. They all start with `<tag:identifier>http`, so finding which lines contain URLs isn't an issue, I just don't know how I can replace the ending tag too. For example, to `<tag:url>http://www.google.com</tag:url>`

What tool can I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`

```
sed -E '/http/ {s/identifier/url/g}' $file
```

This will match any line with `http` and will then substitute `identifier` for `url`

You can also use this `awk`

```
awk -F"[<>]" '$3~/http/{$2="<tag:url>"; $4="</tag:url>"}1' $file
```

Here, we set the delimiter to `<` or `>` and replace the value of columns 2 and 4

**Output**

```
  <tag:identifier>99454</tag:identifier>
  <tag:identifier>97817(web)</tag:identifier>
  <tag:url>http://www.google.com</tag:url>
  <tag:title>Title String/</tag:title>
  <tag:creator>Example</tag:creator>
  <tag:creator>Field</tag:creator>
  <tag:creator>Country</tag:creator>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am on macOS and used `sed -E '/http/ s/:identifier/:idurl/g' file.xml > newfile.xml` and it worked perfectly, thanks for putting me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

When you might have an url like `http://www.identifier.com` you can match every part of the line.

```
sed -r 's#<(tag:identifier)>(.*)</\1>#<tag:url>\2</tag:url>#' file
```